# Vuex binding textarea problems

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4677

Hope to my needs, can be answered.

many thanks.

Comment: You can use v-model along with using state. You need to use the getter on the v-model variable along with get and set functions. I can post a guide on how to do that in my answer if that helps.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/vumoxe/edit?html,css,js,output   This is my demo, you can modify the above,I do not want to operate once to save the database once，thank you